# Если создавать приложения для iOS 6 (iPhone 4), насколько будут совместимы с современными версиями? И наоборот - чего не хватает в старых Target?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple

Вопрос в заголовке.

Откуда такой вопрос - давно уже есть идея создать пиратский "эмулятор", для тех у кого Windows, но кто хочет разрабатывать для OS X и iOS.
Сам пользуюсь VPS, но есть определенные ограничения, и это все же стоит денег.

"Эмулятор" будет представлять собой пиратский образ OS X, запущенный в VirtualBox или VMWare, разумеется модифицированной для удобства использования, наподобие Genymotion, он тоже создан на основе VirtualBox SDK.

С реверс-инжинирингом все идеально, если понадобится - могу дизассемблировать весь OS X с Xcode и iOS Simulator и весь VirtualBox, из x86-64 модулей сделать x86, взять старую версию ОС и "срастить" с компонентами новой, доработать VirtualBox гораздо лучше, чем ее создатели, так что работать все это будет даже на AMD без AMD-v и при 2 ГБ ОЗУ, и т.п.

Но время!

Поэтому на первых порах необходимо ограничиться тем, что возможно достичь достаточно быстро и чтобы было максимально "неприхотливо" к мощности хоста, чтобы не требовало Intel VT-x, а работало и с AMD-v, а лучше вообще без аппаратной виртуализации, чтобы запускать на VPS с Windows Server.

А это навскидку OS X 10.6 (он бывает даже 32-битный), на более расчитывать нельзя.

И, стало быть, Xcode 4.3-4.6, соответствующий эпохе iOS 6 и iPhone 4.

Comment: Я бы не советовал тратить на это время. Последние версии swift будут на вашем эмуляторе недоступны (т.к. нужны последние версии Xcode). Многие функции будут неактуальными для последних версий iOS и нормально протестировать приложение будет нельзя. Это отсечет многих заказчиков и будет делать знания разработчиков устаревшими. Ну и наконец, разработка под iOS/Mac достаточно оплачиваемое дело и позволяет купить б/у Мак или Хакинтош.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk Для окончательного тестирования можно и VPS арендовать, а вот в процессе разработки нужна скорее как раз минимальная версия. Хакинтош? Это и есть Хакинтош, если у вас нормальный ПК с Intel, то для такого случая в моем эмуляторе будет и 10.12. А указанная 10.6 - это минимум, который будет доступным на любом ноутбуке с AMD, и, может быть, даже без поддержки AMD-v.